# How to show Asp.net Pages show on Valid Login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have  created login. If user logs in successfully, `Welcome UserName | Logout` show to user. Now if user log in Product page visible to user else it must be hide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<items>
  <item Text="Home" NavigateUrl="Default.aspx" />
  <item Text="Products" NavigateUrl="Products.aspx"  />
  <item Text="Downloads" NavigateUrl="#"  />
  <item Text="Support" NavigateUrl="#"  />
</items>

<div class="headerMenu">
 <div class="headerTop">
  <div class="templateTitle">
    <a ID="TitleLink" runat="server" href="~/">Project</a>
  </div>
  <div class="loginControl">
    <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
     <a ID="loginLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Login.aspx">Log In</a> |
     <a ID="registerLink" runat="server" href="~/Account/Register.aspx">Register</a>
    </AnonymousTemplate>

    <LoggedInTemplate>
     Welcome <span class="bold">
     <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />
     </span>! [
      <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" 
           LogoutPageUrl="~/" LogoutText="Log Out" /> ]
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking how to implement membership/login or just how to restrict access to the Products page(s)? Can any user access the page(s) or just specified users/those in a particular role? Which version of ASP.NET web forms are you working with?

Comment: just how to restrict access to the Products page(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say you have already created login, this answer assumes you have already set up forms authentication within your application.

In ASP.NET web forms restricting access to pages and managed resources is usually done by grouping those that you wish to only be available to authenticated users into one or more directories, and then using an [authorization element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the web.config file(s) of the directory/directories.

The element can specify either the users or roles you wish to allow access to the page or managed resource.

This example from the MSDN page allows access to users in the role "Admins" and denies access to all other users.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow roles="Admins"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Grouping pages that need protection into one or more directories (each with a child web.config file defining the authorization attribute and allow/deny rules) works due to the cascading nature of configuration files. The application web.config file overrides the machine.config, and is itself overridden by matching rules in a child directory, which are themselves overridden by matching rules in a further child directory - and so on.

The web.config file in the directory is not the same as in the root of the application - simply containing those elements you wish to override from the application root. Authorization in this case.

Your site may therefore end up with a structure a bit like-

```
 -Application root
  -Index.aspx (home page)
  -Login.aspx
  -About.aspx
  -Contact.aspx
   --Products
    --Index.aspx (Products page)
    --Order.aspx
   --Admin
    --ManageProducts.aspx
```

If you have a mixture of pages or resources in the same directory, and you wish to protect some and not others, then you can use the [location element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to apply different rules to different files based on their path. This would look something like this-

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Products.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow roles="Customers" />
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately a separate Location rule will be required for each page/path, so - depending on your needs - you may want to set authorization on the application as a whole to be restricted and allow access to all users on those pages you need to using location elements. For example you may want to do this for the home page and logon page (although ASP.NET will allow access to your defined login page by default).

For more information on implementing security in ASP.NET web forms see http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

In ASP.NET MVC (which it doesn't seem you are using based on the code samples) the same thing is done by placing the [[Authorize]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute either on a controller, or on individual actions within the controller. As with the authorization attribute we can specify individual users and roles. For example-

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Customers")]
public ActionResult Products() 
{
   return View();
}
```

For more information on forms authentication in ASP.NET see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but I would suggest checking out [ASP.NET Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) before developing an authentication & authorization framework yourself. Forms Auth is a [well-documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx), secure, proven solution. You can use the default functionality or extend it to suite your needs.